# How to solve memory problem

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks

We have created an application which consumes too much physical memory  **on mouse click or screen touch**. The code of the application is of thousands of lines and is developed in C++.

So far our approach is to free the memory is to minimize the application. But this approach have consequences. So we are looking for alternative way to solve the problem. This application runs on full screen mode.

Comment: So basically your question is "our application has memory leaks, where are they"?

Comment: What do you mean? And if i knew the area where the memory is leaking then i should not be asking for the help. That is why I mentioned that I need an alternative solution.

Comment: I don't see a statement that there's a leak here, rather an aggressively hungry app whose design might be changable. If there **is** a leak then it's a whole different story, it's a bug and they need strategies to locate the bug.

Comment: @djna: I agree with you. There is no memory leak. Is there any other way to release the memory? Because its a real time application and changing the design will take months.

Comment: I can't think of any silver bullet here. If you can identify the large chunks of memory you may be able to refactor to explicitly manage those allocations. Once you have a single class with responsibility for allocating you have a chance to define responsibiulity for deleting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in an difficult position - discovering this kind of problem in a late stage of development is unfortunate. It's quite likely that fundamental redesign is needed.

I infer that some particular code path, in response to a user event, is very hungry for memory. You need to understand exactly what's happening and how best to improve things. We can't help with that without far more details. But an example I've seen in the past: are you grabbing a whole load of data from some database and keeping it all in memory? Do you really need all that data all the time. can you offload more of the query to the database?

You also need to look at what "too much" memory means. Are you targeting too small a machine? Perhaps just splashing out a few tens of pounds on more memory is cheaper than spending many developer days squeezing a quart into a pint pot?

Edited in response to comment:

OK then this does sound like a leak. You should be able to identify the places where you allocate memory, presumably there should be some kind of symmetry, where there are paired frees. I would start by just identifying the allocations, something is gabbing 2MB, should be possible to find it. Then understand when that memory should be released, for example once a screen has been displayed, or when a user session ends. Then find out why it's not happening. You may need to look at your overall strategy for memory management. Smart pointers? Some kind of manager with a house keeping thread? Overall you need a clear design philosophy to resource acquisition and release. This is hard to retrofit to an existing app, so you have my sympathy.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually there is no database on client side of the system. The whole database is on server side. My company is in ATM machine production(hardware as well as software). So the machine has to remain switched on for 24/7. The clicks made by customer for transaction is the cause of increasing memory. The increase rate of the memory is 2MB per 4clicks. After a certain amount of clicks the application gets hang or crash. So increasing physical memory is not the feasible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will surely try your suggestion with my team.